# Excel - find nth match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I created a like to follow the inventory on an item.

I'm looking to find "What's the next date of availability?"

I found my answer with a index match function, but the problem is :

For each orders, what's available to promise... when my Running Total is not covered by the next "stock Arrival" how to find the "2nd" best match (next arrival)..

Maybe I'm overthinking this..

Here is my workbook : 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwbUB7pydqnfemQwQW9JaFoxbGs

Anyone is an Excel guru?

Comment: Please be sure to upvote good answers and mark answers as solutions.  These are a sort of "thank you" for help you were given at no charge.

Comment: Sure as soon as the answer is found I will!  Cheers

Comment: I updated my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check [edited file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2x_I7I1nAg1SGNFMk1nRFVwTnc). This formula is very comlicated, but it takes into account that, what would be if the second

Put this array formula and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> and fill down:

```
=IF(K2=0,INDEX(A3:E$17,MATCH("05 - arrival",A3:A$17,0),5),IF(SUM($G$2:G2)+INDEX($G$2:$G$17,SMALL(IF($G$2:$G$17>0,ROW($G$2:$G$17)),1)-1)+INDEX($G$2:$G$17,SMALL(IF($G$2:$G$17>0,ROW($G$2:$G$17)),2)-1)>0,INDEX($E$2:$E$17,SMALL(IF($G$2:$G$17>0,ROW($G$2:$G$17)),2)-1),INDEX($E$2:$E$17,SMALL(IF($G$2:$G$17>0,ROW($G$2:$G$17)),3)-1)))
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Hi, I see but I'm not sure to how to use this for each row of the column L.. do you have an example?

Comment: check my file attached above

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the next instock date?  For example, `L2` shows the next arrival date is 11/25/16, but on that date you can clearly see that it will be `Not Instock`.  So, instead you would like to tell the customer when it will be instock - see column M - which shows the date of the next instock arrival date.

To do this, I used a 'adjusting' range `INDEX() and MATCH()` formula: `=INDEX(E2:$E$17,MATCH("Instock",I2:$I$17,0))`

**Notice** there are no `$` dollar signs around `E2` and `I2`.  This will allow the range to adjust as the formula is copied down, making sure the previous dates are not in the formula (only present and future dates - nothing from the past).

[image: Arrival Date & Next Instock Date]

Comment: Hi, yes and no, I see what you mean but I need to consider if the RunTotal is covered.  In H2 and H3  qty are covered by Nov 25th arrival but in H4 next arrival is not enough to cover the order, so next available date should be Jan 27th.

Comment: In fact in M2 and M3  Instock date should be NOV 25th, because nov 25th arrival is covering the RunTotal.

Comment: I see what you mean now... I'm thinking you might be able to do this with an array formula (Ctrl+Shift+Enter), but it might be a Macro or UDF.