# Return row number from Excel sheet based on filters

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following excel file with two sheets namely Sheet1 and Sheet2. Sheet1 contains few names with repetitions like below.

```
           Column E  
 -------- ---------- 
  Row 3    tom       
  Row 4    jerry     
  Row 5    mick      
  Row 6    tom       
  Row 7    john      
  Row 8    mike      
  Row 9    mick      
  Row 10   eric      
  Row 11   matt      
  Row 12   mike
```

I want to be able to determine **the row in which, for example, the second occurrence of the name "Pete" occurs**. For this I have to set up a new worksheet (Sheet2) that will allow me to enter a person's name and a positive integer (such as n), and returns the row in which the name occurs for the nth time.**

```
Enter Name : tom (cell B1)
Enter Integer : 

Result : `2`
```

For the result cell I have applied the below formula which is returning the no. of times the name occurs.

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet1!E3:E12,Sheet2!B1)
```

But I am not been able to find the desired answer.

Can it be done to with Countif, Countifs, Count, CountA, and CountBlank Functions?

Can anyone please help?

Comment: I think this is exactly what you need: https://exceljet.net/formula/get-nth-match

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel - find nth match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40682772/excel-find-nth-match)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(myRng=B1)*ROW(myRng),B2)
```

**Explanation**

> `myRng=B1`  match each entry in myRng with the name in B1 giving an array of `TRUE;FALSE`
>
> `1/…` changes that to an array of `{DIV/0,1,...` depending on whether it matches
>
> `*ROW(myRng)` converts that to an array of `{DIV/0, row_num`}
>
> `AGGREGATE(15,6,resultant_array,B2)` returns the nth smallest value from that array, ignoring the errors